# AM/PM does not show

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime

I have following field in my model:

```
[DataType(DataType.Time)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:hh:mm:ss tt}")]
public DateTime TimeFrom { get; set; }
```

with following code in my view:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TimeFrom)
```

But when I start the application all it shows is e.g. **01:00:00**

Why doesn't it Display the AM/PM?

Answer (score 1):

From this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) I pulled the following:

```
// This example displays the following output to the console: 
//       d: 6/15/2008 
//       D: Sunday, June 15, 2008 
//       f: Sunday, June 15, 2008 9:15 PM 
//       F: Sunday, June 15, 2008 9:15:07 PM 
//       g: 6/15/2008 9:15 PM 
//       G: 6/15/2008 9:15:07 PM 
//       m: June 15 
//       o: 2008-06-15T21:15:07.0000000 
//       R: Sun, 15 Jun 2008 21:15:07 GMT 
//       s: 2008-06-15T21:15:07 
//       t: 9:15 PM 
//       T: 9:15:07 PM 
//       u: 2008-06-15 21:15:07Z 
//       U: Monday, June 16, 2008 4:15:07 AM 
//       y: June, 2008 
//        
//       'h:mm:ss.ff t': 9:15:07.00 P 
//       'd MMM yyyy': 15 Jun 2008 
//       'HH:mm:ss.f': 21:15:07.0 
//       'dd MMM HH:mm:ss': 15 Jun 21:15:07 
//       '\Mon\t\h\: M': Month: 6 
//       'HH:mm:ss.ffffzzz': 21:15:07.0000-07:00
```

Based upon this, it looks like you just need the following:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:T}")]
```

to get "9:15:07 PM" as an output. Caveat: I have not tested this one to ensure it works.

I am also not sure of why the "tt" you have isn't being honored. Have you tried writing the value to code using the property to ensure it works?

```
 string formattedString = myObject.TimeFrom.ToString("{0:hh:mm:ss tt}");
```

This might help you get insight to ensure you have the right format string.

**Update**

I just ran a test on one of my date fields and changed it to a time field with the following:

```
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public DateTime LastInventory { get; set; }
```

Output for DateTime.Now was "06/20/2015 03:12:33 PM"

Comment: Result of your first suggestion: 12:00:00 Result of your second suggestion: formattedString = "{0:12:00:00 }"

Comment: Hi Martin. Thanks for the test. But my output is without PM. Could it be because of the culture info?

Comment: Potentially. Try creating a date after 12pm and see if you are getting 24h format (13:00:00 for 1pm) when doing ToString with it.

Comment: No. I'm getting 1:00:00